# Virtual Machine Server on OS X

Tags: vmware-server, mac-osx, virtual-machines

Is there a good VM server meant to run on OS X?  I see VMWare Server runs on linux and windows but not os x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) is the go.

Comment: forgot about them. looks like this is the way to go. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Options are virtualbox which is free and vmware fusion, I don't know of any others.

Comment: these aren't vm servers though

Comment: Trevor, how did you come to that conclusion? Perhaps you need to clarify exactly what you mean when you say "VM server", because the rest of us are under the impression that both those products are indeed VM servers.

Comment: @John Gardeniers According to Wikipedia, VMWare Fusion is a "desktop" virtualisation product, comparable to VMWare Workstation on Win/Linux. VMWare doesn't appear to have a "server"-level virtualisation product that'll run within an OSX install.

Comment: I think this is down to interpretation of the word "server". In this context the virtualization layer is the server, regardless of whether it can run server level guest operating systems. In this respect Virtualbox, Fusion and Parallels (my personal favourite) are all on a par. The term "desktop" shouldn't even be used as that implies that only desktop level clients can be run, which is most definitely not the case for Parallels or Virtualbox (I'm not sure about Fusion). Be very wary of Wikipedia articles, as they can be written by and/or modified by anyone and are not necessarily accurate.

Comment: @John Gardeniers - the only difference I really care about is on a server, each VM can be accessed remotely as it if were a separate machine.  This means I could setup a linux VM to serve a web app on a public domain.  There are some other differences in the way it utilizes the hardware: http://www.parallels.com/products/server/baremetal/